# How make Django save an image to static folther

Tags: python, django

I have a view that receives an image then saves this image in a temp folder. After that, I make some processing in the image and save it in another folder. But I can´t use it because it is not in the static folder of the app it is considered not secure and give an error message. This code works, but the path is hardcoded.

```
        img = request.FILES["image"]
        img_extension = os.path.splitext(img.name)[1]

        # This will generate random folder for saving your image using UUID
        save_path = 'D:/Photo/GFPGAN/inputs/whole_imgs'
        if not os.path.exists(save_path):
            # This will ensure that the path is created properly and will raise exception if the directory already exists
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(save_path), exist_ok=True)

        # Create image save path with title
        uui = str(uuid.uuid4())
        img_save_path = "%s/%s%s%s" % (save_path, "image", uui, img_extension)
        with open(img_save_path, "wb+") as f:
            for chunk in img.chunks():
                f.write(chunk)
        subprocess.call('python D:/Photo/GFPGAN/inference_gfpgan.py --upscale 2 --test_path D:/Photo/GFPGAN/inputs/whole_imgs --save_root D:/Photo/GFPGAN/results',  shell=True)
        shutil.move('D:/Photo/GFPGAN/results/restored_imgs/image'+uui+'.jpg', 'C:/Users/rapha/OneDrive/Área de Trabalho/Harvard/CSW/commerceTest/cs50-commerceM/auctions/static/auctions/images/images'+uui+'.jpg')

        listing = form.save(commit=False)
        print(img_save_path)
        listing.restoredimage  = 'C:/Users/rapha/OneDrive/Área de Trabalho/Harvard/CSW/commerceTest/cs50-commerceM/auctions/static/auctions/images/images'+uui+'.jpg'
        #listing.restoredimage = cv2.imread("D:/Photo/GFPGAN/results/restored_imgs/image.jpg") 
        listing.restoredimage = 'C:/Users/rapha/OneDrive/Área de Trabalho/Harvard/CSW/commerceTest/cs50-commerceM/auctions/static/auctions/images/images'+uui+'.jpg'
        listing.owner = user
        listing.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
```

How can I save the processed image in the correct path?

The erro is : Exception Type:   SuspiciousFileOperation

Comment: Hello, Do you store the file in a `FileField` in some model?

Comment: your question is not clear

Answer (score -1):

Try to put this in your models

```
upload_to='Where you wana save the image. Example: /images. And it will save the image in your file where your project is'
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Add it to your models.

class "Whatever class u need"(models.Model):
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to=/images)